# "load is not defined at onload"

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I've got an old site done mostly in Dreamweaver that I've inherited that stopped working properly the other day and is giving the "load is not defined at onload" error. Below is the offending JavaScript. I know this is crappy Dreamweaver js but we're planning on closing this site and moving the content somewhere else so I don't want to have to rewrite all this js for a site we're going to be closing so I'm just looking for a stop-gap solution. Most of the other threads on this error deal with missing tags but this is some inline JavaScript in the body tag so I'm not sure where to start.

```html
<body 
    bgcolor="#EAEAEA" 
    text="#000000" 
    onload="load();
        MM_preloadImages(
            'images/layout/button1-over.jpg',
            'images/layout/button2-over.jpg',
            'images/layout/button3-over.jpg',
            'images/layout/button4-over.jpg',
            'images/layout/button5-over.jpg'
        )"
        "load()" 
    onunload="GUnload()" 
    topmargin="0" 
    leftmargin="0" 
    marginheight="0" 
    marginwidth="0"
>
```

Comment: I formatted it so we can read it easier. Try changing `)" "load()"` to `); load();"`

Comment: The code is calling a function `load()`. That function does not exist. It also has a random quoted string `"load()"` which does nothing.

Comment: @JeremyHarris Calling `load()` twice in the same `load` event doesn't seem to make too much sense.

Comment: Oof, yep, didn't even notice it was called as the first one. @HereticMonkey is correct, you are missing a `load()` function then.

Comment: Why is there a random `"load()"`?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not being more explicit in my initial post. The sites images had stopped loading and I thought I had it narrowed down to this old javascript but it turns out it was an old .htaccess file buried in an images sub-directory that wasn't working with the latest Apache update. Thanks for all the help.